# Why does bootstrap CDN stylesheet styling differ from import scss styling?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

The styling, specifically the row styling, differs when using the css on the CDN compared to the scss or css that I got from installing react-bootstrap & bootstrap locally. I want to use the SCSS styles so that I'm able to benefit from renaming variables etc.

**CDN (How I want it to look)**
[image: cdn image]

**SCSS (What I want to use, but not how I want it to look)**

[image]

I am using Create-React-App. Here are the files:

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "tire-fill-tool",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.7",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

index.scss

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

index.js

```
import "./index.scss";
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Metric Tire Size</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

TireFillTool.js

```html
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import Data from "./data";
import Jumbotron from "react-bootstrap/Jumbotron";

const TIRE_PLY_STMT = "Choose Tire Ply...";

function TireFillTool() {
  const tireSizeDatabase = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Data));
  const [tireData, setTireData] = useState(undefined);

  const dataSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    metric: Yup.object({
      firstNum: Yup.number()
        .typeError("Please only enter digits")
        .moreThan(0, "Please enter a number greater than 0")
        .required("Required"),
      secNum: Yup.number()
        .typeError("Please only enter digits")
        .moreThan(0, "Please enter a number greater than 0")
        .required("Required"),
      thirdNum: Yup.number()
        .typeError("Please only enter digits")
        .moreThan(0, "Please enter a number greater than 0")
        .required("Required"),
      symbol: Yup.string()
        .notOneOf([TIRE_PLY_STMT], "Please select an option")
        .required("Please select an option"),
    }),
  });

  return (
    <Container fluid="sm">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          metric: {
            firstNum: "",
            secNum: "",
            thirdNum: "",
            symbol: TIRE_PLY_STMT,
          },
        }}
        validationSchema={dataSchema}
        // validate={(values) => {
        //   const errors = {};
        //   if (!values.metric.firstNum) {
        //     errors.metric.firstNum = "Required";
        //   }
        //   return errors;
        // }}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          const newVals = tireSizeDatabase.metric.filter(
            isSameTireSize(values)
          );
          const avgGals = Math.round(
            newVals.reduce((sum, e) => sum + Number(e.galsBallast), 0) /
              newVals.length
          );
          setTireData({
            tireSize: `${values.metric.firstNum}/${values.metric.secNum}${values.metric.symbol}${values.metric.thirdNum}`,
            gals: avgGals,
          });
          setSubmitting(false);
        }}
      >
        {({
          values,
          errors,
          touched,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          isSubmitting,
        }) => (
          <div>
            <h1 className="pt-4">Metric Tire Size</h1>
            <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="firstMetricNumber">
                  <Form.Control
                    placeholder="Tire Width (mm)"
                    name="metric.firstNum"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.metric.firstNum}
                    isInvalid={
                      errors.metric?.firstNum && touched.metric?.firstNum
                    }
                  />
                  {/* <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                    {errors.metric?.thirdNum}s
                  </Form.Control.Feedback> */}
                </Form.Group>

                <h3 className="ml-2 mr-2">/</h3>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="secondMetricNumber">
                  <Form.Control
                    placeholder="Aspect Ratio"
                    name="metric.secNum"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.metric.secNum}
                    isInvalid={errors.metric?.secNum && touched.metric?.secNum}
                  />
                  <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                    {errors.metric?.secNum}
                  </Form.Control.Feedback>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
                  <Form.Control
                    as="select"
                    // defaultValue={"Choose..."}
                    name="metric.symbol"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.metric.symbol}
                    // isInvalid={errors.metric?.symbol && touched.metric?.symbol}
                    isInvalid={errors.metric?.symbol && touched.metric?.symbol}
                    custom
                  >
                    <option>{TIRE_PLY_STMT}</option>
                    <option>-</option>
                    <option>R</option>
                    <option>B</option>
                    <option>D</option>
                  </Form.Control>
                  <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                    {errors.metric?.symbol}
                  </Form.Control.Feedback>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="thirdMetricNumber">
                  <Form.Control
                    placeholder="Rim Diameter (in.)"
                    name="metric.thirdNum"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.metric.thirdNum}
                    isInvalid={
                      errors.metric?.thirdNum && touched.metric?.thirdNum
                    }
                  />
                  {errors.metric?.thirdNum && touched.metric?.thirdNum ? (
                    <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                      {errors.metric?.thirdNum}
                    </Form.Control.Feedback>
                  ) : (
                    <Form.Control.Feedback>a</Form.Control.Feedback>
                  )}
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
              <Form.Row className="justify-content-center">
                <Button bsClass="xyz" type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                  Calculate Gallons
                </Button>
              </Form.Row>
              {tireData?.gals ? (
                <Jumbotron className="mt-3">
                  <h1>{tireData.gals} gallons</h1>
                  On average {tireData.gals} gallons of Beet Juice will fill a
                  {tireData.tireSize} tire approximately 75% full
                  <p>
                    Did you know that Beet Juice is freeze resistant to -35° F,
                    non-toxic, biodegradable, water soluble, <i>and</i> animal
                    food grade safe?
                  </p>
                  <Button
                    href="https://www.google.com"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                    Find Your Nearest Beet Juice Dealer
                  </Button>
                </Jumbotron>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
            </Form>
          </div>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, in the button and the input fields the bootstrap's classes are working, the problem is in JSX's file, share it and we will help you in your structure. Maybe the div container doesn't have the "row" class.

Comment: I just edited it & added that file. Why would changing the method of getting the style sheet affect it? I would have thought that if the Form.Row component wasn't correct it wouldn't have been styled regardless of which style sheet was used.

Comment: Because the component Form.Row doesn't have the class "row" that class is reserve to Bootstrap's clasess to use it. It's working?

Comment: Yes, it works with the css. I am using Form.Row component from the react-bootstrap library instead of adding a div with the "row" class.